# How to avoid repeated code in D3.js selection attribute functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript

For my project, i display network data on a D3 graph (switches, routes and stations)
All these equipments are linked. In order to link equipments to each other, i list all the equipments from all switches.
Then, i draw a line for each equipments to its corresponding switch.

in the enter() and update() i manipulate the X1, Y1, X2, Y2 attributes and my question is how avoid to call a function twice. 
In the following code: `let eqt = SwitchesHelper.getEqtFromEquipmentName(d, this.ACS.equipments.switches)` is a quite time consuming function and is called twice in enter() and twice in update().
Is it possible to calculate eqt only once?

Thank you for your help.

```
let switchesToPortEquipments = this.switchesToPortEquipmentsGroup.selectAll('line')
        .data(SwitchesHelper.getArchiEquipments(this.ACS.equipments.switches));
    switchesToPortEquipments.exit().remove();
    switchesToPortEquipments.enter()
        .append('line')
        .attr('x1', (d) => {
            let eqt = SwitchesHelper.getEqtFromEquipmentName(d, this.ACS.equipments.switches);
            if (eqt !== null) {
                return eqt.x;
            }
        })
        .attr('y1', (d) => {
            let eqt = SwitchesHelper.getEqtFromEquipmentName(d, this.ACS.equipments.switches);
            if (eqt !== null) {
                return eqt.y;
            }
        })
        .attr('x2', (d) => {
            let eqt = SwitchesHelper.getEquipmentFromName(d, this.ACS);
            if (eqt !== null) {
                return eqt.x;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        })
        .attr('y2', (d) => {
            let eqt = SwitchesHelper.getEquipmentFromName(d, this.ACS);
            if (eqt !== null) {
                return eqt.y;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        });

    switchesToPortEquipments
        .attr('x1', (d) => {
            let eqt = SwitchesHelper.getEqtFromEquipmentName(d, this.ACS.equipments.switches);
            if (eqt !== null) {
                return eqt.x;
            }
        })
        .attr('y1', (d) => {
            let eqt = SwitchesHelper.getEqtFromEquipmentName(d, this.ACS.equipments.switches);
            if (eqt !== null) {
                return eqt.y;
            }
        })
        .attr('x2', (d) => {
            let eqt = SwitchesHelper.getEquipmentFromName(d, this.ACS);
            if (eqt !== null) {
                return eqt.x;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        })
        .attr('y2', (d) => {
            let eqt = SwitchesHelper.getEquipmentFromName(d, this.ACS);
            if (eqt !== null) {
                return eqt.y;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: `getEqtFromEquipmentName` sounds like a perfect job for a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). You could put a Map in the outer scope accessible by both the enter as well as the update selection and fill the map in either `.attr("x1")` or in an initializer before doing the selection.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i used a map to make  dictionaries (key value) of my list of switches object.
So, instead of parsing the entire list searching for a specific switch name, i can get it using the dictionary:
`let eqt = this.switches_list['switch_name']`

Thanks a lot for your help